# attempt to index global 'e_con' (a number value)

Tags: lua, freeswitch

```
lua: els_bgapi.lua:20: attempt to index global 'e_con' (a number value)
stack traceback:
        els_bgapi.lua:20: in main chunk
        [C]: in ?
```

Please help me am new to Lua and FreeSWITCH when ran the code below got the error above

```
sock:bgapi("originate","{sip_cid_type=pid,origination_uuid=uuid,origination_caller_id_number=65181,originate_timeout=10}sofia/external/sip:81245@10.20.16.135 5000")

e_con= sock:events("plain","all");
if (e_con) then
  print(e_con:getHeader());
else
  print("not e_con")
end
```

Comment: It seems that `sock:events` returns a number, not an object that you can call `getHeader` on.

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff  Job-uuid is number something like this: +OK Job-UUID: f719939a-ffa1-49ca-a8b6-7f080febc2dc.

Answer (score 0):

`events` command just do subscribe to events but not read any events from connection.

`bgapi` works like you send command to FS. FS returns reply with job id. But in this time FS may not start execute command yeat. You have to wait `BACKGROUND_JOB` event with correct job id.

So you have to subscribe to `BACKGROUND_JOB` (or to all like you do but be prepare to handle many other events).

Then send `bgapi` and read job uuid from response or pass your own job uuid so you can filter events before you get response form FS. Then do loop with `recvEvent`.

I do not use original ESL library but there exists examples in FS books.
Also I works on my own [ESL implementation for Lua](https://github.com/moteus/lua-lluv-esl) base on LibUV library

Comment: you are correct i subscribed  e = sock:sendRecv("events plain all") and set 
e = sock:recvEventTimed(30), job_uuid = e:getHeader("Job-UUID"); so with that I got the Job_uuid.

Comment: you are correct i subscribed  e = sock:sendRecv("events plain all") and set 
e = sock:recvEventTimed(30), job_uuid = e:getHeader("Job-UUID"); so with that I got the Job_uuid.please i would to know how to implement ESL using LibUV Library I will appreciate any documentation on this. kindly pardon my ignorance am a lua beginner.